# SIGABRT when casting one TableViewController to another

Tags: swift, xcode, segue, sigabrt

This is from the 'Everyone Can Code' eBook from Apple. The variable names are changed for my personal uses.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    guard segue.identifier == "saveSegue" else {return}

    let website = websiteTextField.text ?? ""
    let email = emailTextField.text ?? ""
    let username = usernameTextField.text ?? ""
    let password = passwordTextField.text ?? ""
    account = Account(website: website, username: username, email: email, password: password)


}
```

This is the segue function. relatively simple

```
@IBAction func unwindToAccountsPage(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        guard segue.identifier == "saveSegue" else {return}
        let sourceVC = segue.destination as! AddAccountTVC

        if let account = sourceVC.account {
            if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                accounts[selectedIndexPath.row] = account
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
            } else {
                let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: accounts.count, section: 0)
                accounts.append(account)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
        }
    }
```

There is a `SIGABRT` on the `let sourceVC = segue.destination as! AddAccountTVC` line, saying that it

> Could not cast value of type 'Password_Alcatraz_2.AccountsTVC'
>   (0x1019d6468) to 'Password_Alcatraz_2.AddAccountTVC' (0x1019d61b0).

Those two are different table view controllers. I am new to swift, so I do not understand exactly why it will not let me pass data between them. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check the class associated with your destination VC in the Storyboard.  It is apparently set to `AccountsTVC` when it needs to be set to `AddAccountTVC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as @Vacawama states - go to your storyboard and look at the ViewController you are GOING TO - you have it listed as a AccountsTVC when in your code you have that listed as a AddAccountTVC

`let sourceVC = segue.destination as! AddAccountTVC`

so one of them is wrong. Just adjust and you are good

Comment: thanks. I'm new at this so I appreciate the patience aha